# For loop is not looping

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to create a CD key generator in python and I'm generating the key in four chunks, each 4 digits long. I'm using a for loop to generate the characters from a list of all alphanumeric characters and appending them to a string, `chunk1`.

```
# 4 digits to be generated
for i in range(0, 4):
    chunk1 = ""

    # Choose randomly whether the next character will be a letter or digit
    uld = randint(0, 1)
    if uld == 0:
        character = 'letters'
        # Randomly choose a letter from all upper- and lowercase letters
        selector = randint(0, 51)
    elif uld == 1:
        character = 'digits'
        # Randomly choose a digit from 0-9
        selector = randint(0, 9)

    # Set `chunk1` equal to itself and append the selected digit
    chunk1 = chunk1 + charset[character][selector] # References the `charset` dictionary
```

`charset` is a dictionary with two keys, one for upper- and lowercase letters and the other for digits from 0-9

```
charset = {
    'letters': 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'digits': '0123456789'
}
```

The issue is that the `for` loop is not generating 4 characters, but rather just one and I can't seem to figure out why. I may be missing something rather obvious.

Comment: Maybe if you moved `chunk1 = ""` to _outside_ the loop, it'd start "looping"...

Comment: Yep, like i said, obvious mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chunk1` is overwritten in every iteration.

Instead, you should store the values in a list.
You also don't need all of these string concatenations

```
output = []

for i in range(0, 4):
    # Choose randomly whether the next character will be a letter or digit
    uld = randint(0, 1)

    if uld == 0:
        character = 'letters'
        # Randomly choose a letter from all upper- and lowercase letters
        selector = randint(0, 51)

     elif uld == 1:
        character = 'digits'
        # Randomly choose a digit from 0-9
        selector = randint(0, 9)

    output.append(charset[character][selector])

print(''.join(output))
```

Answer (score 0):

`chunk1 = ""` can you move this outside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you say `chunk1 = ""` in the loop. This means, that you reset the variable to "" everytime the loop runs. Just put it outside of the loop and it works just fine: https://repl.it/Nlkj/0